# 80040154 error - interop.outlook.namespace class not registered - CLSID={0006308B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}

Tags: vb.net, office-interop

Am using visual studio 2010 vb. Using .net have added a reference to microsoft.office.interop.outlook type=.net version 12.0.0.0 copy local = false path = ...microsoft visual studio 10.0/../pia/office12

Using regasm.exe microsoft.office.interop.outlook.dll I have registered this assembly. 
Using the /regfile option I have viewed the contents. The clsID that it can't find ( CLSID={0006308B-0000-0000-C000-000000000046}) is not in this regfile. I would think that it should be.
This classID on the MSDN site brings me to the Office 2010 Outlook.Namespace Class.  For Office 2007 no clSID is listed.

In the GAC there is microsoft.office.interop.outlook.dll version 12.0.0.0 is registered.

When I run my application I get the above runtime exception.

What do I need to do to handle this problem.

Comment: Yes, it is an Office 2010 (version 14) specific CLSID, I don't have it either.  How you ended up referencing it when you used the version 12 interop library is a mystery to me.  You should however not run regasm on the interop file, that screws up the PIA registration.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to avoid the issue of having the wrong version of Office dlls is to use late binding, so that it doesn't reference any specific version of the dlls.

There are some downsides in that you can't use the real types from the Office object model and so won't have Intellisense for the automation objects, and if you've already written all the code you'd have to change your code, but depending on your circumstances it might be worth it.

The following article explains the differences between early and late binding and has sample code for each: [How To Use Visual Basic .NET for Binding for Office Automation Servers](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304661)

Answer (score 0):

You can possibly hit the 32-bit <-> 64-bit wall.

- The OS can be 32-bit or 64-bit Office
- 2010 can be 32-bit or 64-bit
- and your process can be "any cpu" or 32-bit or 64-bit.

so you want to make sure all this is consistent. For example if the OS is 64-bit, Office is 32-bit and your app is "Any CPU" you will likely get this error. (maybe Office 2010 actually supports that...)

Answer (score 0):

I discovered the problem.  I was instantiating the Namespace when it just had to be declared. 
Specifically:

Imports Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook
 Dim myapp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
 Dim ns = new outlook.NameSpace
 ns = myapp.getNameSpace("MAPI")

When I changed it to the following my runtime error disappeared and it ran fine:

Dim myapp As Outlook.Application = New Outlook.Application
 Dim NS = myapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")